# Design for C# program to populate database

Tags: c#, database, oop, database-design

I'm new to OOP and software design in general and I've been tasked to create a program to populate a database from a set of data sources.  My question is at a high level, what would be a good/flexible/logical way to design the classes?  The target database that I'm to build has approximately 40 already definied tables.  Furthermore, these tables are grouped into 10 sets (lets call them TableSets) of related information.  My initial idea was to have 3 classes: `DataBase`, `TableSet`, and `Table`.

- The DataBase class would hold an array of the TableSets (1 through N)
- The TableSet class would have an array of the Tables in that TableSet
- The Table class would just hold data

For the methods I was thinking of having something like

```
DataBase.PopulateTableSet(tableSetNum)
TableSet.PopulateTable(tableNum)
Table.RunQuery or some other method to get the right data
```

If anyone has any suggestions on what a good way to do this is, I'd really appreciate any kind of help.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: There are far too many variables to answer this as stated.  Entire books are written on the subject, teams of developers design Object-Relational Models, .NET already has tons of stuff built-in, rendering half of your question unnecessary, and you haven't even specified if you want to use WinForms. ASP.NET, Silverlight, Console applications, or ...  I'm not trying to be critical or mean-spiritied, just explaining my vote to close, as this question isn't answerable in the present format.  My best advice would be to go to www.asp.net and watch some of the tutorials to get an idea of the basics.

Comment: Could be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to read about is a three layered application development paradigm. Essentially you'll need to design a class that can read and write to a datasource, e.g. an SQL data source, access... etc...

Next up you'll want a logic layer (sometimes referred to as business logic). In your logic classes you'll do things like build up sql statements, run calculations etc... and finally a GUI layer (win forms or whatever it is you'd like to use).

You may want multiple classes in each layer, e.g. SQL class, MSAccess class or whatever data sources you'll be reading and writing.

You may wish to look up DataTables, check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can go for ORM (Object Relation Mapping). ORM's can map you DB tables (Relations) to classes in your code. You won't need to do much work by hand. 
If you are using C# you can use Entity Framework or Nhibernate. For Java you can use Hibernate.

You can use these links for further study:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

http://nhforge.org

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

http://www.hibernate.org/

Answer (score 0):

I am not new to OO; but, I am new to C# and the application I am developing now works closely with a Database.  For that application I chose to use the Entity Framework and it has made working with a Database almost transparent.

I found the Database First approach to be very easy.  All you do is create the Database then add an Entity Model and have Visual Studio create it from the Database.  Then you will have a list of classes that you use to do the database work for you.

If you are starting the DB yourself, it is a can be a big help to follow some comventions such as naming the tables with 'plural' names and don't use Underscores (Ex: If you a 'user' table, call it 'users').

There are a several videos that you can watch to help get you started.  Here is an [video series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BS6IKdUd2V8) I found that gave me a good start.  I found others too; but, I'll have to find them again.